# Cake PHP Validation not happening

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Im new to cakePHP.I just learning the way to validate the data before storing into the database.I just did the following validation to check the birth date given by the user.

```
 class User extends AppModel {
            public $name = "Users";
            public $validate = array ( 
                    'birth_dt' => array ( 'rule' => 'date',
                    'required' => true,
                    'allowEmpty' => false,
                    'message' => 'Please Give valid date' ));


    }
```

I expected a error message when I give wrong data in the birth_dt field.But there is no errors in case of wrong data ,bug the data is not getting store in the database.If I give the valid data also the data is not getting stored.If I remove the validation part then  data getting stored in the database.
     It not only happen for date ,it happen for other fields like alphaNumeric ,email which I used in my form.Any one please tell what I did wrong.

This is my controller code,

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController{
        var $name = 'Users';
        var $uses = array('User','Dob');
        var $helpers = array('Form');

        function index() {
                if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                        if ($this->request->data) {
                                $this->User->save ( $this->request->data );
                                $this->Session->setFlash("User Added!");
                                $this->redirect('/users');
                        }

        }

}
```

Comment: It will be good if you provide some code from your controller ...

Comment: Now I have added the controller code

Comment: I tried both ,but still now the problem is there.

Comment: Are you saving your records using index function ? Normally, we have `add` function. So Just need to confirm..

Comment: A slight, unrelated to your question, comment: Regardless of whether _valid_ data is submitted, you're flashing 'User added!' to the client. You should check whether `save()` succeeds before setting that flash message.

Comment: Also, could you maybe post (the relevant bit of) your view code?

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple possible issue.Try following.

1. Before saving user Create new record like `this->User->create();`
2. You don't have `else` part. Write like following in else & check,

   else {
                               $this->Session->setFlash(__('User could not be saved',true));
                       }

Comment: Both are unlikely to solve the problem. 1 doesn't create a new record, it sets the model to save as a new model when you add data and save (just calling $this->User->create() won't save a new record AFAIK) and 2 won't help saving data either, it is good practice and might help debugging.

Comment: hmm actually I think this could help.. to add a new record you DO need to call the `create()` method before `save()` or else it's an update.. and reading the code, it will always display "user added!" even if it's not true.

Comment: @pleasedontbelong: The part about always displaying 'user added' is true, I already commented that under the question. Unless it's changed in CakePHP 2.0, calling create() isn't _necessary_ to do an insert. If you haven't specified an id, there won't be an update, so that's not the issue here. In any case, it's not _the_ problem because regardless of insert or update the validation _should_ take place.

Comment: @Joep you're right, it's not necessary, however it's a good practice to add the create() cause that way you could be sure that you are making an insert and not an update. (maybe he has an id in the form and he has being updating the same record, and thinking that the validation is not working).. anyway, we'd need to see the POST data to be sure :) cheers

Comment: for me "if ($this->request->data) {" looks unnecessary, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check why **save()** failed by examining the **validationErrors** array in the **User** model.  From the **UsersController** it can be access via **$this->User->validationErrors**.

Furthermore, your controller logic isn't quite right.  A was mentioned in some of the comments, you don't check if **save()** was successful and you always state that a user was added, even when it's not true.

Try something like this:

```
    if($this->request->is('post') && !empty($this->data)) {
        if($this->User->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('User added!', 'flash_good');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Could not add player.', 'flash_bad');
        }           
    }
```

This way, when **save()** fails for some reason, the user will remain in that action and the form will still be populated with the data the user entered.  Furthermore, if you use **$this->Form->input(...)** to create you form elements the validation errors will be added to the form automagically.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `public $validate` is wrongly written

Try this

```
class User extends AppModel {
        public $name = "Users";
        //For more strict validation you should have more than one parameter
        //submitted to the rule array for date which requires the user to enter 
        // exactly what you need. for example 01/01/12 instead of 01/01/2012 
        //Please check the following address
        //http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::date
        //However, this should work fine.

        public $validate = array ( 
                'birth_dt' => array (
                    'rule' => array('date'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'allowEmpty' => false,
                    'message' => 'Please Give valid date'
                )
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best way for validation is to integrate server side and client side validation.
form fields should be validated on focus out/blur with ajax call to server side validation rules via your controllers. This will ensure consistency in server side and client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

bla..bla :)
I think validate error message not show 
because you use `$this->redirect('/users');`
when redirect cakephp will be render view that clear message error :)

You can comment line `//$this->redirect('/users');` and then try again :)